# Updating a Record in Mongo After Retrieving Its ID From Another Record

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to make an API point that would do the following. I submit an Object ID in the path. The record with that ID is found. Then, the program looks into a certain field of this object. The field contains an ObjectID for another entry in the database. At last, I need to pull up that record and increment a certain field in it.

In short, I have a `child->parent` relationship between certain records and would like the ability of incrementing a certain field within the parent record by submitting the child's id to the API point.

Here is the code I had that did the basic child increment. How can I go about doing it for the parent?

```
router.get('/today/parent/up/:id', function(req, res){
        var collection = db.get('Activity');
        collection.update({
            _id: req.params.id
        },
        {
            $inc: {
             "repetitions.today": 1,
             "repetitions.total": 1 
            }
        }, function(err, activity){
            if (err) throw err;
            res.json(activity);
        });
})
```

Comment: There are no relations in mongoose cause its not relational database. Are you using references? If so, you can populate reference and then update it. Remember that you cannot update reference directly by object in which reference occurs. Tell us more about your "relation"

Comment: I am not sure about the references. What I do is store parent's ObjectID in one of the fields of the child object. Maybe this is not the best practice. What is a better way?

Answer (score 2):

First use mongo references, heres documenttion: 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/

here's mongoose documentation
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/populate.html

Basically You need to do this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
, Schema = mongoose.Schema

var PersonSchema = new Schema({
    name    : String
, age     : Number
, stories : [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});

var StorySchema = new Schema({
    _creator : { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' }
, title    : String
, fans     : [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' }]
});

var Story  = mongoose.model('Story', StorySchema);
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', PersonSchema);
```

Then you could use .populate() method, and then you could extract your populated model and make changes and save them with .save(), but remember to use it in populated model, not the parent one. For ex. You've got author which contains reference to books, so you make request

```
author.findOne({'name': 'King'}).populate('books').exec((err, king) => {
  let book0 = king.books[0];
  book0.title = 'I need to change this one';
  book0.save((err, data) => {
    console.log('saved referenced object')
  }
})
```